# Is it possible to solve this only using python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

https://codefights.com/interview/wqveBLtNtfByaEnfW

While I understand how to solve this problem using for loops, I'm wondering if I could get to the answer using only regular expressions.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work...

```
import re

def simplifyPath(path):
    path = re.sub(r'/[a-zA-Z]{1,}/\.\./', '/', path)
    path = re.sub(r'//' , '/', path)
    path = re.sub(r'/\./', '/', path)
    return path
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible with one single pass and one single regex. You'd need some stack functionality to keep track of the current depth. Still, I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: How would you simplify something like "/a//b/../../c/"? It gets tricky. The most readable solution applies your three replacements until the string stops changing.

Comment: You should add the problem to your question, instead of just linking it.

Answer (score 0):

Although we might elaborate some tricky regex like this (with recursion and PyPi regex):

```
(?<=\/)\/|(?<!\.)\.(?:\/|$)|((?:\w+\/)\g<1>?\.\.(?:\/|$))|\/+$
```

it would be rather too complicated and probably still not covering all edge cases: see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKY1rH/1).

Applying a series of simple regexes seems to be the most viable solution:

```
path = '/' + path                           # secure from missing root
path = re.sub(r'/+', '/', path)             # remove any slash repetitions
path = re.sub(r'(?<!\.)\.(?:/|$)', '', path)    # remove any "./"
while True:                                 # remove any "dir/../"
    pp = re.sub(r'\w+\/\.\.(?:/|$)', '', path)
    if pp == path:                          # NB: we have to do this in a
        break                               # loop until path remains unchanged
    else:                                   # to cope with input like this:
        path = pp                           # '/a/b/../c/../../d'
path = re.sub(r'\.\.(?:/|$)', '', path)     # remove oustanding '../' (cf. '/a/../../b')
path = re.sub(r'/$', '', path)              # remove trailing slash
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/I5B084

Comment: Thank you! As a regex newbie this is very helpful

Answer (score -1):

Why use regex when there is python.
Regex is poorly debuggable and badly readable.
I gave it because the many bugs and poor language

In python it just dirs=split("/") and then eat dirs from the start.

```
testdirs=["a/b/../c/d/e/./f","p/q/r/..","e/../..","e/."]
for dir in testdirs:
    simpdir=dir.split("/")
    out=[]
    for branch in simpdir:
        if branch=="..":
            if len(out)!=0:
                out.pop(-1)
        elif branch!=".":
            out.append(branch)
    print "/".join(out)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. Still, you can test your code in the OP's [link](https://codefights.com/interview/wqveBLtNtfByaEnfW) and see how it fails for `"/home/a/./x/../b//c/"`.